# sort one incomplete dataframe based on a complete dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have two dataframes for a classification problem. df_x (the data, an unfinished puzzle, with zeros in the unfilled positions) and df_y (the labels, the finished puzzle).

The dataframes have a few hundred thousand lines, so efficiency is important.

The problem is that I don't have guarantees that the ith index of df_x corresponds to the ith index of df_y. I would like to fix the dataframes so their indexes are matching.

I have this very inefficient implementation, however I cannot affor keeping it.

```
x2y = [].
no_label = []
for i in df_x.index:
    a = df_x[i:i+1] #receives one line of df_x at a time.
    a = a.loc[:, (a != 0).any(axis=0)] #excludes the zeros (unfilled parts of the puzzle)
    match = True 
    for j in df_y.index: #loops over all lines of df_y
        for a_i in a:
            if (a[0:1][a_i].item() != df_y[j:j+1][a_i].item()):
                match = False #if one element is not present in the final solution, than it goes to the next line in df_y
                break
        if match:
            x2y.append((i,j)) 
            df_y[i:i+1] = df_y[j:j+1] #replace label at the position of interest
            break
    if not match:
        no_label.append(i) #unsolved puzzles with no label
```

that is how the dataframes look like:

```
df_x.head()
Out[58]: 
    0    1    2      3    4      5   ...   75   76     77     78   79     80
0  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  168.0  ...  0.0  0.0  886.0    0.0  0.0  973.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  168.0  ...  0.0  0.0  886.0  899.0  0.0  973.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  168.0  ...  0.0  0.0  886.0  899.0  0.0  973.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0    0.0  0.0  168.0  ...  0.0  0.0  886.0  899.0  0.0  973.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  149.0  0.0  168.0  ...  0.0  0.0  886.0  899.0  0.0  973.0

[5 rows x 81 columns]

df_y.head()
Out[59]: 
      0      1      2      3      4   ...     76     77     78     79     80
0  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0
1  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0
2  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0
3  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0
4  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0

[5 rows x 81 columns]
```

I am starting with pandas, so please be gentle!

**EDIT** One of the comments asked for an example of how the matching dataframes would look like. So the following is a hand made example:

```
df_x.head()
Out[59]: 
      0      1      2      3      4   ...     76     77     78     79     80
0    0.0  126.0    0.0  149.0    0.0  ...    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  997.0
1  111.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  152.0  ...  953.0    0.0    0.0  984.0    0.0
2  112.0    0.0  137.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0  961.0    0.0    0.0  997.0
3    0.0  121.0    0.0    0.0    0.0  ...    0.0  962.0  973.0  984.0    0.0
4    0.0    0.0  133.0  144.0  155.0  ...  956.0    0.0  978.0    0.0    0.0

df_y.head()
Out[59]: 
      0      1      2      3      4   ...     76     77     78     79     80
0  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0
1  111.0  123.0  139.0  147.0  152.0  ...  955.0  968.0  973.0  984.0  991.0
2  112.0  126.0  137.0  149.0  154.0  ...  956.0  961.0  973.0  982.0  997.0
3  119.0  121.0  138.0  147.0  156.0  ...  959.0  962.0  973.0  984.0  995.0
4  116.0  127.0  133.0  144.0  155.0  ...  956.0  962.0  978.0  989.0  992.0
```

Comment: From what you have posted, I can only tell that you are doing it wrong. When you use a loop in Pandas, you are _almost always_ doing it wrong. However, I cannot understand what you are trying to do. How do you match rows? Add an example of two matching rows from two dataframes.

Comment: I totally agree that loops and pandas were not made to love each other! But I could not find anything that would do the job for me.

Comment: Are _all_ existing values in a column identical?

Comment: No, but there are many rows that repeat themselves. 10 to 15 times the same row is very common.

Comment: Please add an example  of different rows. It is not clear at all what you are trying to do.

Comment: I changed the example. Hopefully is it clear now. The dataframes have matching rows (df_y is completed and df_x has zeros in many fields), but the indexes don't. I want to re-arange the rows of df_y in such a way that all not zero values of the ith row in df_x match the values of the ith row of df_y.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to `pandas`! This is a pretty hard problem, because it looks like you want to do 1e5 * 1e5 comparisons, which isn't going to be fast no matter what we do, so let's try and limit that as much as possible. First, do your best to have a reasonable expectation that the matching indices will be close. Second, here's some code that will make your matching a bit easier.

For two series x_row and y_row:

```py
> x_row = pd.Series([1, 2, 0, 4])
> y_row = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
> ((x_row == y_row) | (x_row == 0)).all()
True
```

That last row is a bit-wise or (`|`) between two checks: first, if each value matches the corresponding value in the other series (`T, T, F, T`) or the value in x_row is zero (`F F T F`). The bit-wise or of those two Boolean series is `T T T T`, so the result is that `.all()` are True.

Here is an example of using that in context, as well as trying to limit the number of comparisons made by only taking a row of `y_df` out of the running once its match has been found. In the ideal scenario, this would run only as many times as you have rows.

```
x2y = []
unmatched_x = []
unmatched_y = df_y.index.tolist()
for x_idx, x_row in df_x:
    match = False
    for y_idx in unmatched_y:
        if ((x_row == df_y.loc[y_idx]) | (x_row == 0)).all():
            match = True
            break
    if match:
        unmatched_y.remove(y_idx)
        x2y.append(x_idx, y_idx)
    else:
        unmatched_x.append(x_idx)
```

If you think that *most* of them match, you can sort out the ones that do by running

```py
matches = ((df_x == df_y) | (df_x == 0)).all(axis=1)
```

This does the same kind of thing, but on the whole dataframe at once. It will return a Series of booleans, corresponding to whether or not each row of `df_x` matches the corresponding row of `df_y`. Then you can triage the ones that don't.
`df_x[matches]` will be just the rows that do match, or `df_x[~matches]` will be the ones that don't.

Comment: Thanks for the piece of code. It definitely made it faster, but the rows still don't match. The reason for that could be a problem with the logic in the algo you described OR a problem with my data frames. I am checking that